# RHEL8.8 need to download all packages and dependencies for use on another RHEL 8.8 System

Tags: linux, yum, download

I have a customer on RHEL8.8/4.18 and their systems do not have internet. I need to install my co. software via rpm package as well as all dependencies on their system. It sounds easy but, what a day!

Ultimately, once I get all the packages and dependencies download to a surrogate host, I need to be able to take those packages to the customer and install dependencies and SW locally.

I tried yum --pluggin-downloadonly and this does not install!  plugin unknown

I tried yumdownloader --resolve and this did download many dependencies but not all

I tried dnf also failed.

In these cases, 'failed' = all dependencies DID not download properly. Only some packages downloaded correctly with required dependencies.

It's still a mess because the packages that did download with dependencies I am finding they too have dependencies!

How do I get the dependencies properly?  I see some packages work fine (e.g. httpd) and some do not work (e.g. automake)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using RHEL 8.8, you should have access to the [RHEL DVD (requires RedHat login)](https://developers.redhat.com/content-gateway/file/rhel/8.8.0/rhel-8.8-x86_64-boot.iso) with all of the available packages on it.  You should then be able to transfer it to any usable medium and configure a DNF repository from it.

Comment: Thanks Grace I will check the DVD.

Comment: I checked the dvd and noticed that not all packages are on there.  I have RHEL 8.8 iso (11.6 GB) but it does not include all the dependencies either (e.g. automake, perl, etc).  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how you came to the conclusion that packages are missing, I had no issue finding both `perl` and `automake` in the `AppStream` repository on the exact DVD I linked.

Comment: No kidding?  How can that be?  I must be doing something wrong.  Can you tell me the path on the DVD where you are finding these packages?  Thanks man.  Mucho appreciation!

Comment: Path to `automake` on the DVD is `${DVD_MOUNT}/AppStream/Packages/automake-1.16.1-7.el8.noarch.rpm` but you really should be configuring the DVD as a DNF repository source so you can use the DNF workflow to install packages.

Comment: Grace.  I understand.  Thanks much for your feedback!  SSD_DUDE